# Database Design - Use a FK or Separate Table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Say I have a Table named 'A'. Table 'A' can have either a 1:0 or 1:1 relationship to table 'B'. About 95% of the rows in table 'A' will not have a reference to any row in table 'B'.

So, I could do this two different ways.

## 1

In table 'A', I could have a FK column to table 'B'. However, roughly 95% of the rows will contain a NULL value in this FK column.

## 2

I could create a table 'C' which contains a FK column to table 'A' and a FK column to table 'B'. I would then only add a row to table 'C' in the 5% of the cases where I do have a relationship between tables 'A' and 'B'.

I should also mention that a row in table 'B' could point to many rows in table 'A'.

Which would be the preferable way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Update: You have a N:0..1 (which is different from 1:0..1). In that case, your 2 solutions are the only possible solutions. In practice, it probably depends which case you want to optimise; I would go for simplicity of one less table.

Normally, the simplicity of solution 1 would make it preferable. You can easily do joins with table B and you can filter for NULL/NOT NULL without joins.

In theory, solution 2 is closer to the theoretical normalization ideal; in practice, it is complex and the only situation that I can imagine is better is in the case that space is at a premium and your tables are really huge; however, if that were the case, probably you need to go to some NO-SQL schema.

EDIT: THIS PARAGRAPH IS NOT VALID: You are missing another possible solution. Have a foreign key in B pointing to A. From what you say in your question it seems that every record in B must have a record in A. Therefore, you can point from B to the primary Key in A, and there will be no empty records in any table. Of course, you lose the ability to check the for records in A without a corresponding B without a join.

In order to decide which strategy to use, probably you need to make more specific what you are going to query and your use cases; then, you can optimise for a certain strategy.

Comment: I edited my question to include the fact that a row in table 'B' could reference many rows in table 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend the first one.

Instead, I would recommend table B contains a FK to table A,  then about 5% of rows in B will contain a NULL where no relationship applies.

The second approach of the third table C is more normalized but the trade off is to perform an extra join each time you want to query the relationship.

Comment: I edited my question to include the fact that a row in table 'B' could reference many rows in table 'A'.